# How to move active directory web app from tomcat to wildfly

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, war, wildfly

I'm trying to move a web app (war file) from tomcat to wildfly. It use active directory to login to the web app and on tomcat have no issue. But when I deploy it to wildfly it would kept on asking for user and password and showing the following error:

> 16:04:22,450 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX000283: Bad password for username user
>   16:04:22,451 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX000206: Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: PBOX000070: Password invalid/Password required
>       at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:284) [picketbox-4.0.21.Beta1.jar:4.0.21.Beta1]
>       at org.jboss.as.security.RealmDirectLoginModule.login(RealmDirectLoginModule.java:147) [wildfly-security-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:762) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:690) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:688) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:687) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>       at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:595) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>       at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:408) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.21.Beta1.jar:4.0.21.Beta1]

In the context.xml the Realm is configure as follow

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" debug="99"
       connectionURL="ldap://mycompany.com:888"
       connectionName="ldap@mycompany.com"
       connectionPassword="******"
       referrals="follow"
       userBase="OU=MyCompanyUser,DC= mycompany,DC=com"
       userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
       userSubtree="true"
       roleBase="OU=GROUPS,DC= mycompany,DC=com"
       roleName="name"
       roleSubtree="true"
       roleSearch="(member={0})"
        />
```

I try to load the [catalina](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/catalina/6.0.16) jar and its dependencies as a module on wildfly but that didn't work.

Is there a way I can configure wildfly, without modifying the war, so the active directory web app work on wildfly deploy?